# Python ModuleNotFoundError 'smored' even though folder smored has __init__.py

Tags: python, module

I have a Python app that the team has developed, and if I run "docker-compose up" and then run the unit tests, they work great. So that part is awesome.

But I am responsible for making sure our app gets built, and the Docker image built, in Jenkins. And in Jenkins, I use the "docker build" command, and then the "docker run" command, and set the CMD to our script "runtests.py". Obviously, we need to run the tests automatically in Jenkins. And when I do this, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smored'
```

So I added some debugging information in our runtests.py script:

```
print(" os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) " + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))) 
print(" os.getcwd() " + os.getcwd()) 

try:
    user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
    print(" PYTHONPATH " + user_paths)
except KeyError:
    print(" There was a KeyError when we tried os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep) ")

list_dir = os.listdir(".") # returns list
print("contents of cwd directory")
for item in list_dir:
    print(item)

try:
    list_dir = os.listdir("smored") # returns list
    print("contents of smored directory")
    for item in list_dir:
        print(item)
except:
    print("In the current working directory, we could not find a path called 'smored'")
```

And it looks like the script is executing in the correct directory, and in this directory there is a folder called "smored" and inside of that there is an empty file called **init**.py. So there should be a module named "smored" and this error should not happen.

The next 2 lines in runtests.py are these:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'smored.settings.test'
django.setup()
```

The script dies on this next line, when we call django.setup.

Why would this code give this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smored'
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
print(" os.getcwd() " + os.getcwd())
```

showed that when Docker was running the CWD was `/app`.

I added the `settings` folder to the `sys.path`:

```
sys.path.append("/app/")
sys.path.append("/app/smored/")
sys.path.append("/app/smored/settings/")
```

Then I was able to simplify `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings.test'
django.setup()
```

And then things finally worked.

Hope this save someone the hours of headache this caused me.